# Select all results but Order by condition on single column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have records in a table:

```
ID  Name Group JoinDate    ActiveDate
1   A    12    11-01-2015  25-05-2015
2   A    19    12-06-2014  27-08-2015
3   B    16    03-09-2015  12-04-2016
4   B    35    05-05-2013  21-07-2015
5   B    39    06-09-2015  14-08-2016
```

From the data, I need a result set like below:

```
ID  Name Group JoinDate    ActiveDate
2   A     19   12-06-2014  27-08-2015
1   A     12   11-01-2015  25-05-2015
5   B     39   06-09-2015  14-08-2016
3   B     16   03-09-2015  12-04-2016
4   B     35   05-05-2013  21-07-2015
```

Result set is based on the `ActivityDate` order by `desc` for each Name; `A` should order by `ActivityDate` and `B` order by `ActivityDate`

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

A simple query is all you need...

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
ORDER BY Name, ActivityDate DESC
```

Comment: I think they want `order by name, activityDate desc`

Comment: Yeah could be @xQbert

Comment: I need the result ordered by Activity date desc and that should happen for each Name..

Comment: This query will do that.  If @scsimon has helped you please [consider accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) his/her answer.  This will reward the contributor and help others, with similar problems, to find a working solution.

Comment: @scsimon it's not me that has the issue KBR is the poster.  and I'm the one who up-voted your answer after the update on order by.

Comment: haha my bad @xQbert. Rookie mistake on my part :) Nice bobby tables shout out on your profile.

Answer (score 0):

Just Make your sentence as query.

```
SELECT
    ID,
    Name,
    Group,
    JoinDate,
    ActiveDate
FROM
    [Your_Table]
ORDER BY
    Name ASC,
    ActivityDate DESC
```

you can refer this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp) to upgrade your skills.